# Angularjs view object with key

Tags: angularjs, object, view

I have the following object in my view in AngularJS:

**This works:**

```
{{settings.fonts.font_weight.type}}
```

I get an output value.

**This don't work**

```
{{settings.fonts.[key].type}}
```

"key" is a value that can be output by {{key}} and it outputs "font_weight".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the dot:

```
{{settings.fonts[key].type}}
```

You have to chose between [bracket or dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) :)